# How to pass multiple model functions from controller to view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

## Controller

I have multiple functions from the `model` passing data to the `view`

I was doing this successfully like this:

```
$var1 = $this->model_name->function_name();
$var2 = $this->model_name->function_name();
$var3 = $this->model_name->function_name();

$data = $var1 + $var2 + $var3; 

$this->load->view('page_name', $data);
```

Now I am using the above method in other areas which is working flawlessly. However I am getting an error **Fatal error: Unsupported operand types** What happened? Why was it working an hour ago and suddenly broke without modification to the code..

Comment: Can you spot the line which causes the error based on the message you get? Is it `$data = $var1 + $var2 + $var3; `

Comment: Yes that was what the error was suggesting however the problem was in the model. One of the vars wasn't being returning properly which was throwing that exception. I added an `If` to ensure to check for num_rows and all is working again. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put multiple variables into array like  this:

```
$var1 = $this->model_name->function_name();
$var2 = $this->model_name->function_name();
$var3 = $this->model_name->function_name();

$data = array(
               'var1' => $var1,
               'var2' => $var2,
               'var3' => $var3,
          );

$this->load->view('page_name', $data);
```

or as Rick suggested you can use this:

```
$data = array();
$data['var1'] = $this->model_name->function_name();
$data['var2'] = $this->model_name->function_name();
$data['var3'] = $this->model_name->function_name();

$this->load->view('page_name', $data);
```

More on array: [PHP Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: just to expand on this, the "Fatal error: Unsupported operand types" means that one or all of your $var are not arrays but could be variables.  In order to do "+", all variables must be arrays.  What Otporan is doing is declaring the $var within the array rather than relying on "+".

Comment: You might also want to take into mind using variable names that actually mean something ie $data['userdata']=$this->model_name->function_name();

Comment: You can also use the [compact function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) for less code. e.g. `$this->load->view('view_path', compact('var1', 'var2', 'var3'));`