# Load multiple models within same function of controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have two functions in my model as

```
class Jobseeker_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
public function result_getall($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');    
        $this->db->from('tbl_jobseeker');
        $this->db->where('tbl_jobseeker.User_id',$id);
        $this->db->join('tbl_work_exp', 'tbl_jobseeker.User_id = tbl_work_exp.User_id','left');
    $query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row();
    }
    public function select($id) 
    {   
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('tbl_qualification');
        $this->db->where('tbl_qualification.User_id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }
}
```

And in my controller I have a function as

```
public function display()
    {
      $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
      $data['row'] = $this->jobseeker_model->result_getall($id);
      $res['a'] = $this->jobseeker_model->select($id);
      $this->load->view('jobseeker_display.php', $data,$res);
}
```

It is not possible to display the view page.. I could pass two variables into my view page.right?

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849725/how-to-pass-multiple-model-functions-from-controller-to-view-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass your any number of variables/arrays using a single array.
In Controller:

```
public function display() {
      $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
      $data['var1'] = $this->jobseeker_model->result_getall($id);
      $data['var2'] = $this->jobseeker_model->select($id);
      $this->load->view('jobseeker_display.php', $data);
}
```

In View:

```
`$var1` and `$var2` will be available.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your two variable using single srray

```
public function display()
    {
      $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
      $data['row'] = $this->jobseeker_model->result_getall($id);
      $data['a'] = $this->jobseeker_model->select($id);
      $this->load->view('jobseeker_display.php', $data);
     }
```

Views

```
foreach($a as $data){
// your code
}

echo $row->column_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function display()
    {
      $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
      $data['row'] = $this->jobseeker_model->result_getall($id);
      $data['a'] = $this->jobseeker_model->select($id);
      $this->load->view('jobseeker_display.php', $data);
}
```

Comment: If you want $res then use this, `$data['res']['a'] = $this->jobseeker_model->select($id);`